# error installing .apk in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I'm new to android development.  I've installed eclipse and updated all the android packages.  Now i'm trying to run the .apk file that was provided by my app developer to test it in the emulator.

I'm installing it via a download from the web.  Once the package is downloaded, when I click on it, it says "installing".  Then it says Not Installed.  The app runs fine on my phone.  But I want to test it with different screen resolutions and sizes, screen captures etc.

I've tried it with several different emulators from 2.3 to 4.0, and I get the same error.
I'm running eclipse on a mac.

Comment: Try uninstalling the app from the emulator first , then install it

Comment: Capture the logcat from the emulator during the install attempt.  BTW, the android simulator is something distinct (and at this point probably obsolete) from the emulator everyone is familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading the apk inside the emulator and then attempting to directly install it inside the emulator, that may be the problem as the emulator does not include the Android Market (now Google Play).

Download the apk on your Mac first, and then install using adb as follows:

```
adb install <apk_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling the app from the emulator, Open a terminal and to the directory where you installed android-sdk, then go to platform-tools. Give command `adb install yourAppName.apk` 
Post the error log if this fails.
(To view the error log, open another terminal and go to android-sdk-installation directory > platform-tools, give command `adb logcat`. Keep the log running while the apk is installing.)

Comment: I think this is important part of the log.


E/PackageManager(   54): Package com.brainstorm.bluetoothFinder requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
W/PackageManager(   54): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.brainstorm.bluetoothFinder.apk
D/AndroidRuntime(  203): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  203): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit